# How to check whether two sets contain the same objects

Tags: java

I have a class `IntegerType`:

```
public class IntegerType implements DataType {

    private int value;

    public IntegerType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public NativeType nativeType() {
        return NativeType.INTEGER;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Integer.BYTES;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer value() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (o == null || o.getClass() != getClass()) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            IntegerType integerType = (IntegerType) o;
            if (this.value == integerType.value()) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I essentially want to check whether two sets containing instances of `IntegerType` are the same based on whether the instances have the same `.value` parameter:

```
IntegerType int1 = new IntegerType(1);
IntegerType int2= new IntegerType(1);
Set<IntegerType> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(int1);
Set<IntegerType> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.add(int2);

System.out.println(set1.equals(set2));
```

However running the above code prints out `false`. From what I understand it should print `true` since `int1.equals(int2)` is `true`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, `HashSet` requires you to override the `hashCode` method, which it uses to determine whether or not two objects could possibly be equal. Here is a possible implementation:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + value;
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/M2XIwg)